# CSS or layout issue with surveyor in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, layout, surveyor-gem

Image A
[image: Image A: The Deployed]

Image B
[image: Image B: The Local]

I have a problem with my layout or my css, in my local pc. This is where I originally developed the site with surveyor. The output of surveyor is like the Image B. But when I deployed it to the server and edited some css and layout, now the outcome is like the Image A. I can't get it back to normal. Is anyone having the same issues as mine?..Can someone tell me what's causing this?..or even better, how to fix this?..xP

Thank you very much in Advance!!!

Joshua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now solved! hehehe...

Just change the production.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

to false

it is located on the config/environment. xD